# How to see the documentation or source code of a method instead of typing in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Pycharm 2019.1.2
- Python 3.7

Test Source Code:

```py
with open('./demo.py') as f:
    f.readline()
```

If use the Pycharm's `Scientific Mode` to see the Documentation, it only show the `typing hint` as below:

[image]

But if use `Ipython`, I can see the documentation:

```
In[2]: f.readline?
Signature: f.readline(size=-1, /)
Docstring:
Read until newline or EOF.

Returns an empty string if EOF is hit immediately.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Comment: Ipython has evaluated the code and can therefore correctly identify the objects type while Pycharm can only make an educated guess of the type and shown the generic interface.